# Pca9685 & WS2818B, 1 Nano

Tags: arduino-nano, i2c, servo, led-strip

Arduino n00b here. I currently have an Arduino Nano set up to run 6 servos from a PCA9685 board. I'm looking to add 6 switches and 6 LED indicators to switch servo positions. What I'm curious about is how to connect the WS2818B. I know they can be run through I2C, but the Pca9685 is using those wires. Can I run both the pca9685 and the LEDs through I2C or just run each LED through a separate pin?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at WS2818B [datasheet](https://www.tme.eu/Document/ddc250a349c0084fadc3ded4c327f335/WS2818B.pdf), they do not use i2c. It just needs a single ( dedicated) pin to receive the color/brightness commands.